# Foreach statement in .Net Core View

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core

I want to loop thru each item for a View in the code below and not sure how to do it. This is what I have so far.

I haven't tried anything except this and have researched examples but none that meet this specific example.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Packet.Meeting" class="control- 
        label">Date/Time Of Meeting:</label>
            <input asp-for="Packet.Meeting" type="date" asp-format=" 
       {0:MM/dd/yyyy}" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Item)
        {<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Item.ItemTitle" class="control-label"> 
        </label>
                <input asp-for="Item.ItemTitle" class="form-control" />
            </div>}            
      </div>
      </div>
```

Here is what model looks like:

```
 public class PacketViewModel
  {

    public Packet Packet { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I want to show all of the item titles from the item model

Comment: What does your Model look like?

Comment: More specifically, is `Item` in your model a collection?

Comment: Updated to show model

Answer (score 0):

Pass model from your controller

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
    //create your obj and assigned all the values

   PacketViewModel list = new PacketViewModel(); //Ienumerable ModelList class defined under Model will store the list of Model data.
   // assuming you have assigned all the values to your obj

   View(list);
}
```

Now in your view page we will explicitly mention the model

```
@model Project.Models.PacketViewModel
```

Now you can iterate through your model:

```
 @{

        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
           //do what you want to do here for example 
           <b> @item.ItemTitle </b>
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're referencing the model at the beginning of the view you should be fine:

```
@model ProjectNameSpace.Models.PacketViewModel
```

Now, if you use a `foreach` loop, the inputs will all have the same `name` and `id` attributes in the HTML:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.items)
{
    <label asp-for="@item.ItemTitle" class="control-label"> </label>
    <input asp-for="@item.ItemTitle" class="form-control" />
}
```

So, we'll have to use a `for` loop instead:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.items.Count(); i++)
{
    <label asp-for="@Model.items[i].ItemTitle" class="control-label"> </label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.items[i].ItemTitle" class="form-control" />
}
```

Using the for loop will give the inputs unique `id` and `name` attributes in the HTML.

Comment: Not sure if the @model List<PacketViewModel> will work in the view because Packet.Meeting is not a list only the Item.ItemTitle. If I use model List<PacketViewModel> then Packet.Meeting does not contain a definition for model List<PacketViewModel>

Comment: @bootsy Ah I see, so my second example is what you needed. I'll update my answer

Comment: @bootsy Any luck?